# In SQL how to increment a varibale in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

So I have a table A as follows

```
Message code trig timestamp
 a        x    1    T1
 a        x    1    T2
 a        x    0    T3
 b        y    1    T4
 b        y    1    T5
 a        x    1    T6
```

I want the following result

```
Message code trig timestamp  groupbycolumn
 a        x    1    T1           1
 a        x    1    T2           1
 a        x    0    T3           2
 b        y    1    T4           3
 b        y    1    T5           3
 a        x    1    T6           4
```

I need to group the rows according to message, code and trigg but ordered by the timestamp. So if a new message, code and trigg value comes then it should have a new number in the groupby column. Note that a,x 1 in the first line has a groupby value 1 and the one in the last has 4.

```
declare @chngeVal int;
set @chngeVal=0;

select n.Message,n.code,n.trig,

case when n.Message<>n.nextMessage or n.code<>n.nextCode or   n.trig<>n.nextTrigg
then @chngeVal+1
else @chngeVal
end as groupbycolumn,

n.timeStamp
from (  select Message,code,trig,timestamp,
lead(Message) over (order by timestamp asc) as nextMessage,
lead(code) over (order by timestamp asc) as nextCode,
lead(trig) over (order by timestamp asc) as nextTrig
from A  ) n
```

If I could get the case to do a  @chngeVal= @chngeVal+1 it would work, but I cannot do that in case. Would anybody know how to change the value of a variable in a query.

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: Be careful when tagging. mysql <> sql server.

Comment: 5 years later, were you able to @chngeVal= @chngeVal+1 ? Because i'm stuck at the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the difference of `row_numbers()` or `lag()` and cmulative sums:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when message = prev_message and code = prev_code and trig = prev_trig
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (order by timestamp) as groupbycolumn
from (select t.*,
             lag(message) over (order by timestamp) as prev_message,
             lag(code) over (order by timestamp) as prev_code,
             lag(trig) over (order by timestamp) as prev_trig
      from a
     ) a
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Please note that (a,x,1,T1)(a,x,1,T2) should have the same groupbycolumn value and (a,x,1,T6) a different groupbycolumn value because even though(a,x,1) is the same, there was a change in value before it happened again

Comment: @Aparna . . . That is exactly what this should do.  This should do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I broke the solution into a three part query using two CTEs:

1. `CreateIds` produces ids I use to identify the rows in the next two parts.
2. `Firstrows` gets only the rows that start each group, and determines the unique id for each group as well as the row id that starts the next group (`NexdtGroupRowId`).
3. Finally, I produce the result by joining `Firstrows` to a range of rows from `CreateIds` that have a rowId between the rowId of the first row and the rowId of `NextGroupRowId` - 1.

My feeling is that this is inefficient as heck, and there's a way to do this with a recursive CTE.  But since you started using window functions I just went in that direction.

```
WITH createIds AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [timestamp]) AS RowId
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Message, code, trig DESC) AS GroupId
    FROM src
)
, firstrows AS (
    SELECT a.RowId
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.RowId) AS OrderedGroupId
        , LEAD(a.RowId, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY a.RowId) NextGroupRowId
    FROM createIds a
    LEFT JOIN createIds b ON b.RowId = a.RowId - 1
    WHERE a.GroupId != b.GroupId OR b.GroupId IS NULL
)
SELECT a.[Message], a.code, a.trig, a.[timestamp], r1.OrderedGroupId
FROM firstrows r1
INNER JOIN createIds a ON a.RowId >= r1.RowId AND (r1.NextGroupRowId IS NULL OR a.RowId < r1.NextGroupRowId)
ORDER BY a.[timestamp]
```